# Use Householder reflectors to show det($I + xy^T$) = 1 + $y^T x$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem is stated in the title. $x,y$ are any vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n.$ I'm aware of the classical proof which doesn't involve Householder reflectors but am honestly at a loss as to how to approach this proof.

It seems like I would have to apply reflectors to $G = I + xy^T$ in such a way  that I end up with an identity matrix in rows/columns 1 through $n-1$, and then $1 + y^T x$ in the bottom right position, simply because I can't think of any other kind of matrix that would allow me to find a determinant of the form that's requested. But I tried doing a Householder reflection on $G$ in the style of finding $G = QR$, and things get messy very quickly, so I don't think that's the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the right idea. Let $P = I - 2 \frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}$ where $v = x - \Vert x \Vert e_1$, so $P$ is a Householder reflection such that $Px = \Vert x \Vert e_1$. Then, recalling that $P$ is symmetric and orthogonal,
$$\begin{equation}
P(I + xy^T)P = (P + \Vert x \Vert e_1 y^T)P
             = I + \begin{bmatrix} \Vert x \Vert y^T P \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}$$
so $\det(I + xy^T) = 1 + \Vert x \Vert (Py)_1$. But
$$\begin{align}
v^Ty & = x^Ty - \Vert x \Vert y_1 \\
v^Tv & = 2 \Vert x \Vert( \Vert x \Vert - x_1),
\end{align}$$
so
$$\begin{equation}
(Py)_1 = \bigg(e_1^T - 2 \frac{v_1v^T}{v^Tv}\bigg)y = y_1 - \frac{x_1 - \Vert x \Vert}{\Vert x \Vert(\Vert x \Vert - x_1)}(x^Ty - \Vert x \Vert y_1) = \frac{x^Ty}{\Vert x \Vert},
\end{equation}$$
and the result follows.